# Toolkit.getImage(URL url) works with Java 8 but fails with Java 11

Tags: java, java-8, nullpointerexception, embedded-resource, java-11

I'm having a problem with a Java SE Swing application. It compiles fine on both Java 8 and 11, but it fails on the latter in these lines:

```
    URL url = Object.class.getResource("/org/mozillatranslator/resource/mt_icon_small.gif");
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

    Image img = tk.getImage(url); // Raises runtime exception
```

with this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImageFromHash(SunToolkit.java:653)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImage(SunToolkit.java:689)
    at org.mozillatranslator.gui.MainWindow.loadIcon(MainWindow.java:232)
```

As I've said, the line works on Java 8, but fails on Java 11 with the exact same JAR. I've searched for a change in Java behavior in versions beyond 8, but I haven't found anything. Has anyone suffered a similar situation, or can suggest any possible workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
URL url = <YourClassName>.class.getResource("/org/mozillatranslator/resource/mt_icon_small.gif");
```

or

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread()
    .getContextClassLoader()
    .getResource("org/mozillatranslator/resource/mt_icon_small.gif");
```

`Object` is [loaded by bootstrap class loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)), so `Object.class.getResource()` uses [system class loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResource(java.lang.String)).

Check return values with empty string parameter; `Object.class.getResource("")`, `YourClass.class.getResource("")`, and `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("")`.

Comment: There’s more to it than just class loaders. Since Java 9, the environment takes care to locate the resource of the right *module*. So you should call `getResource` on a `Class` object belonging to the right module. And you should *not* use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` . This will again lack any information about the right module and even worse, make the call on an arbitrary, *changeable* class loader someone has placed there via `setContextClassLoader(…)`.